# Visualizing a set of points in $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: geometry, complex-geometry

As the title says, I want to find a way to visualize the set $S=\{p=(p_1,p_2)\in\mathbb{C}^2 : |p_1|=|p_2|\}$. I thought of maybe tori? is it a Riemann surface?. How could I find some other description that allows me to answer this question?

Comment: This is not a complex manifold. In fact, it is a cone over a $2$-dimensional torus in the unit sphere $S^3$. If you remove the origin, it will then be a smooth $3$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: How did you arrive at this conclusion?

Comment: First notice $p\in S\implies tp\in S$. Next work out that the intersection with the unit sphere is a product of (congruent) circles.